# Why won't bash escape whitespace or honor quotes in filepaths?

Tags: bash, whitespace, filepath

I have the following script saved as 'lspkg' in my path:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=("$@")

for item in ${args[@]}; do
    echo "$item"
done
```

When I run `lspkg /absolute/path/to/file`, it works as expected, printing the path.  But, the following behaviors are causing me a good deal of trouble:

Escaping the spaces in the path does not really escape the spaces:

```
$ lspkg /absolute/path/to/file\ with\ spaces
/absolute/path/to/file\
with\
spaces
```

Putting the path in quotes does not make bash see it as a single string:

```
$ lspkg "/absolute/path/to/file with spaces"
"/absolute/path/to/file
with
spaces"
```

Why is this, and how can this problem be solved?

Comment: Try putting quotes around the `${args[@]}`

Comment: The root of this problem was actually in the way the script was being run on my machine, but the code I posted does still have an error.

Answer (score 5):

Important quotes are missing from your script, use:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=("$@")

for item in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "$item"
done
```

Without quotes in `"${args[@]}"` shell is expanding and treating it as multiple arguments.